# How can I able to assign account to someone in SalesForce via API?

Tags: salesforce

Is it possible to assign SalesForce Account to someone via API? I checked existing method, but didn't find anything.
I know, that there are exist Account Assignment Rules, but is it possible via API too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would call update() passing in an Account structure that specified the Id of the Account and the Id of the new owner(aka user) in the OwnerId field.

Comment: It was so simple :) Thank you for your answer :)